Do infamous criminals and deceased alumni lose FERPA privacy rights?
I am researching privacy laws regarding student records at US universities in cases where the student has gained public notoriety or is deceased. Recently, there has been media coverage of Luigi Mangione, the 26-year-old charged in the homicide of UnitedHealthCare CEO Brian Thompson. As a researcher studying patterns in academic backgrounds, I wonder about the legal framework for accessing student records in such cases. Specifically, I'm interested in understanding how FERPA and similar privacy laws apply to both individuals who have become subjects of major public interest and to deceased former students. For instance, would academic records of notable historical figures like Richard Feynman or J. Robert Oppenheimer still be protected, or is there a point at which such records become part of the public domain? Does the public figure status of an individual affect their FERPA protections?
I've seen some historians cite academic records of long-deceased individuals in their research, but I'm unclear on the legal basis for this. It would be helpful to understand if there's an established time period after death when academic records become accessible for research purposes, and what processes legitimate researchers need to follow to access such records.
Additionally, I am concerned about potential legal liability. How vulnerable would a university or individual researcher be to lawsuits if they mistakenly disclosed protected academic records? Are there any notable cases where universities faced significant legal consequences for unauthorized disclosure of student records, either of living or deceased individuals? I'd appreciate insights from those with experience in university administration or academic research involving historical student records.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

This might be better at https://law.stackexchange.com/

I agree with Buffy, but if you want to keep it here you should ask either about current notorious figures or about the historical case

As I understand it ?? The institution is supposed to enforce this, and for any breach the victim can only sue the institution, not the researcher.  But, again, this belongs in the "law" forum.

The records of deceased students are not protected: https://studentprivacy.ed.gov/faq/does-ferpa-protect-education-records-students-are-deceased

@NateEldredge isn't that an answer? Though this question is unfocused, I realize.

I wonder why this was closed. Academia-related laws like FERPA are very much on-topic here; we have had FERPA questions before.

@cag51 I voted to close as two many questions, not as off-topic, since I think "deceased" and "in the news" are two different questions.

@NateEldredge - but, equally, lapsed FERPA protections do not compel an institution to release any records either.

@Azor: That close reason makes slightly more sense. Though personally, I think this could be isomorphically formulated as "are there exceptions to FERPA protections, such as dead students or public figures?", so even that seems like a technicality that should be fixed by editing rather than closing.

And "legal liability" is yet a third question.

@cag51 that’d be fine with me and I’d vote to reopen.

@cag51 this user is one of the many who targets various STEM communities writing posts using gen ai. See this Meta post: Reporting the recent infestation of new users resorting to gen AI targeting STEM communities. This particular user has already been suspended in many communities already.
